# Downgrading SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard to Web Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to downgrade a SQL Server running SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition SP1 to 2008 R2 Web Edition SP1.

I discovered this question on Server Fault:

> [Can I downgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard To Web Edition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/387375/can-i-downgrade-sql-server-2008-r2-standard-to-web-edition)

Which links to a similar scenario:

> [Downgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition (trial) to R2 Web Edition (licensed)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/a6a16420-8dd1-4e7f-8003-11c8ed8b44a5)

This server doesn't have Analysis Services installed and I tried to run the Edition "Upgrade" tool and got this failure:

[image]

I checked the detailed report and all that it says is:

Rule Name: *EditionUpgradeMatrixCheck*
Rule Description: *Checks whether the selected instance of SQL Server meets upgrade matrix requirements.*
Result: *Failed*
Message/Corrective Action: *The selected SQL Server instance does not meet upgrade matrix requirements.*

Strangely the Edition Downgrade rule has passed.

I ran this from the SQL 2008 R2 Web Edition DVD.

Can anyone guide me through downgrading this SQL server to Web Edition, I am now at a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately looking at the MS matrix you cannot do this.  You were able to earlier because evaluation versions don't have that lock, but once you go full edition it's locked out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

You could try an approach taken here but proceed with extreme caution.
http://skreebydba.com/2012/11/16/downgrading-sql-server-enterprise-to-standard-with-scripts/

**[edit]:
This URL has the scripts to recreate logins, etc. that Aaron pointed out**
Just a headsup though, this doesn't script out jobs.  If you restore MSDB to recreate jobs, make sure to

```
UPDATE MSDB..SysJobs 
SET Originating_Server = 'SQLServerName'
```

It will also work for downgrades to web.

Comment: That's pretty much the conclusion I was coming to. I was hoping to avoid having to uninstall Standard then re-install Web Edition. Thanks for confirming this.

Comment: My pleasure, sorry to hear you gotta go through that hassle.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling shouldn't be all that painful. Just take backups of all your databases first (and script out logins / jobs etc).